# Java Items from database won't get added to list I've created

Tags: java, mysql, list, label, fxml

So I'm trying to create a program that will display recipes to the user. To do so I want to get items out of my database and put them into a list, but for some reason I get a SEVERE NULL error when I go to the screen where I want to add the variables from the list to our FXML lables.

Here I create the lists
   
    `List<String> stap = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> stapOmschrijving = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> stapAfbeelding = new ArrayList<>();`

This is where I add items from the database to the list: FYI: the database code works for getting simple strings out of the database, but I only get the SEVERE NULL error when trying to put the strings into the lists.

```
try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM receptStap WHERE recept_receptNaam = " + dagGerecht ; 

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {

            stap.clear();
            stapOmschrijving.clear();
            stapAfbeelding.clear();

            while(rs.next()){
                stap.add(rs.getString("stap"));
                stapOmschrijving.add(rs.getString("stapOmschrijving"));
                stapAfbeelding.add(rs.getString("stapAfbeelding"));
            }
        }
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
```

And finally, this is where I add the items to the appropiate FXML labels(in the class made for this fxml file)

```
public class StapReceptenController implements Initializable {

    Connectie connectie = new Connectie();
    Statements statement = new Statements();
@FXML
private Label omschrijving;
@FXML
private ImageView afbeelding;
@FXML
private Label nummer;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    connectie.maakVerbinding();
    statement.haalReceptenOp();

    int counter = 0;
    nummer.setText(statement.stap.get(counter));
    omschrijving.setText(statement.stapOmschrijving.get(counter));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad code.

Why are there three lists of `Strings`?  A better idea would be to encapsulate those three items into a class that makes sense and return a `List` of that class from the query.

You should use `PreparedStatement` and bind parameters rather than concatenating Strings to create SQL.

You should create that `List` of objects and return it from this method.

You should close `Statement` in a finally block.

You should pass in `Connection` and get it out of a pool.

Comment: If anyone runs into the same issue, what Duffymo said above is the correct way to approach this. You want to create a class with the strings and then make a list out of that class.